# & operator with numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, bitwise-operators

I found out something interesting in Python. When I input: 99 & 100 Out is 96. What does '&' do with these numbers? Why is the answer '96'? It looks so wierd...

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It will make more sense if you print those numbers in Hex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bitwise operator. The manipulated unit is the binary representation of the numbers

examples

```
3 10
5 11 &
------
3 10 =
```

and

```
2 01
3 10 &
------
0 00 =
```

Do the same for 99 & 100, you'll get out 96 in binary